# Do App Engine Task Queues have same limitations as Cloud Tasks?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub) says that for Cloud Tasks:

> Maximum push handler/subscriber processing duration: 24 hours (App
> Engine Standard manual or basic scaling)

Is this (and the other limitations) also true if you are using the App Engine Task Queues API? As I understand, before Cloud Tasks, Task Queues had a limit of 10 minutes. Does the fact that Task Queues are running on Cloud Tasks mean that under basic scaling with App Engine, tasks can run for 24 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine Task Queue is the legacy service, bind with App Engine. Now Cloud Task is the unbind service that you can still use with App Engine but with also other services (and that no longer requires App Engine to work).

The limitation are still the same:

- 24h timeout for app engine basic and manual scaling
- 10min ffor app engine automatic scaling
- 30minutes for HTTP tasks

*Be careful, Cloud Functions gen1 has a max 9 minutes timeout. Even is Cloud Task can wait for completion 30 minutes, your Cloud Functions can't live more than 9 minutes.*

*At the opposite, Cloud Run can have a timeout up to 1H, and can continue to work even if the Cloud Task 30minutes timeout is over (and the task considered as failure because of timeout). That latest points is very important if you configure retry policies.*

Comment: Thank you. Will App Engine Task Queue be around for a while? Or will it be deprecated and all App Engine users need to switch to Cloud Tasks?

Comment: I don't know the Google Cloud Roadmap and internal plans. However, I can tell you that App Engine Cron have been deprecated and migrated to Cloud Scheduler. I can predict the same thing for Cloud Task, but, if it's like Cloud Scheduler, it's only a matter of API (and the way how you deploy the resource) not a matter of feature.